# ¿Por qué puedo ignorar valor de retorno de ciertas funciones en C?

Tags: c++, c

Estoy empezando con C y tengo la siguiente duda: ¿Por qué si la definición de la funcion `scanf` indica que retorna un valor entero:

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...)
```

puede usarse sin tener en cuenta este valor de retorno? Lo mismo sucede con `printf`.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
...
printf("Ingrese entero: ");
scanf("%d", &val );
...
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

Por que el valor de retorno no te interesa.

No siempre vas a usar el valor de retorno de una función. Por ejemplo, el entero que retorna scanf es un valor que te indica la cantidad de caracteres leidos, o un numero negativo si nada fue leido.

Si no te interesa saber eso, puedes directamente no recibir el valor de retorno. En ese caso, el valor se descarta y no queda en ningun lado.

Sin embargo, en algunos casos te interesara el valor de retorno, por ejemplo para saber si efectivamente se ingreso un valor. En ese caso, vas a querer saber que retorno esa función, y seguramente vas a querer comprobar que efectivamente se ingreso un valor de determinado largo.

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias. Entonces ese valor retornado no queda en "ningun lado"? se pierde y listo?  Pregunta: puedo hacer lo mismo con funciones que yo defino? de ser asi, para que declaro unas con tipo y otras void?

Comment: Podes hacer lo mismo, pero supongo que si declaras un valor de retorno es porque te interesa. sobre todo si es tuya. podes hacer lo que vos quieras con tus funciones tambien.

Comment: Ahi lo probe con una funcion mia: es como decis. Entonces puedo tener en cuenta o ignorar el valor retornado por cualquier funcion? yo pensaba que si o si tenias que "recibirlo" segun la dfinicion de la funcion. Nuevamente MUCHAS GRACIAS!

Comment: Lo importante con el valor de retorno es que lo  devuelvas, o sea, si definis una función con un valor de retorno tenés que retornar ese valor.

Comment: @SebastianAguirre recorda leer los links que te pase: [tour] y [ask]

Comment: @gbianchi `scanf` retorna la cantidad de argumentos _parseados_ correctamente, `printf` devuelve la cantidad de caracteres impresos y `fputc` retorna el mismo caracter escrito si fue correctamente escrito, de lo contrario retorna `EOF`.

Comment: @NaCl saque la referencia de aca: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm.. pero obviamente te creo mas a vos... igual la explicacion venia por otro lado... ;)

Comment: Te mando tus cariñitos al chat ;)

Answer (score 3):

Efectivamente puedes ignorar el valor de retorno de las funciones si no vas a usarlo. Si la función no se espera que devuelva ningún valor su tipo de retorno será `void`:

```
void función() {
    // no devuelve ningún valor
}
```

Pero si tienes una función que devuelve un valor y quieres que **no sea ignorado**, puedes asignarle el [atributo `[[nodiscard]]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), forzando una alarma de compilación si el valor de tu función es obligatorio que sea recogido:

```
[[nodiscard]] struct algo_importante {
    // Este objeto no debe ser ignorado
};

// Devuelve algo importante
algo_importante función() {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    función(); // Warning! se está descartando algo_importante
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En C++ cambian la forma de definir atributos? En C era `__attribute(([Loquesea]))`

Comment: Los abributos eran dependientes de implementación, ergo: cada compilador definía atributos a su manera. En C++11 se estandarizaron los atributos y en adelante se han ido incorporando atributos estándar al lenguaje, como el mencionado en mi respuesta.